# Setup different Internal IP for worker nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I want to setup a kubernetes cluster locally where I would like to have 1 master node and 2 worker nodes. I have managed to do that but I am not able to access pods or see any logs of a specific pod because Internal IP address is the same for all nodes.

```
vagrant@k8s-head:~$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k8s-head     Ready    master   5m53s   v1.15.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-151-generic   docker://18.6.2
k8s-node-1   Ready    <none>   4m7s    v1.15.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-151-generic   docker://18.6.2
k8s-node-2   Ready    <none>   2m28s   v1.15.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-151-generic   docker://18.6.2
```

In order to resolve this problem I have found out that following things should be done:
- add `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip=<IP_ADDRESS>` in */etc/default/kubelet* file 
- restart kubelet by running:
`sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl restart kubelet`

The problem is that */etc/default/kubelet* file is missing on this location and I am not able to add this additional parameter. Tried with creating file manually but it looks like it is not working when I restart kubelet, IP address is still the same.

Anyone faced this issue with missing /etc/default/kubelet file or if there is another easier way to setup different Internal IP addresses?

Comment: Check your kubelet config location by `systemctl status kubelet`, you will get output like `/usr/bin/kubelet ... --config=<kubelet_config_location>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It is normal to have the same IP in every node for the Kubernetes Cluster running in VirtualBox**, the reason is that it is a `NAT newtork` not intended for communication between virtual machines, the 10.0.2.15 IP is NATed when accessing the outside world.

The following diagram shows the networks that are created in a Kubernetes Cluster on top of VirtualBox, as you can see, every node has the same IP in the `NAT newtork` but different IPs on the other networks:

[image: Kubernetes Cluster Networks]

In order to access the PODs you can use a NodePort and the `HOST ONLY` network.

See a full example and download the code at [Building a Kubernetes Cluster with Vagrant and Ansible (without Minikube)](https://www.itwonderlab.com/ansible-kubernetes-vagrant-tutorial/). It is a tutorial that explains how to launch a Kubernetes cluster using Ansible playbooks, Vagrant and VirtualBox.

It uses Calico for networking and it includes another tutorial for installing **Istio** if you need a micro service mesh.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed response I will definitely take a look at the example you have provided. I have already created Host only network and in order to expose nodes to IP's provided from Host only network I wanted to edit /etc/default/kubelet file.
I have found out that I was using wrong IP address inside /etc/default/kubelet file by accident, when I finally changed it to correct IP it worked after kubelet restart. Now, each node has it's own IP address and I am able to access pods that I have created.

Comment: for me, I didnot edit the file /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf, I created a new file /etc/default/kubelet, add --node-ip there, and now I can see nodes got the correct INTERNAL-IP and "kubectl logs" works